# best way to encrypt a folder backup (tarball or zip)

Tags: python, centos, backup

I currently have a python script that creates a gzip tarball of a few folders and ships them off t Amazon S3 for archived backups. The folders contain my ever so precious code and data, so I'm wondering whats the best way to encrypt these backups with a password for added peace of mind in case my AWS account was ever compromised?

Comment: it is a pretty open-ended question... I doubt you'll get much in the way of answers. However, here's something to get you started: [gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/) and [GnuPGInterface](http://py-gnupg.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Lucas - 10 years ago zip encryption was trivial to crack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use GPG (GNU Privacy Guard, the GNU implementation of the OpenPGP standard), there's a wrapper module for Python at https://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/

One big advantage of using GPG is the ability to implement asymmetric cryptography:  You would generate a public/private key-pair and only need to store the **public** key in the configuration for your python script.

The **private** key would only be necessary to decrypt the data later, and as such wouldn't have to be accessible from your python script.

Disclaimer:  I haven't personally used the GPG python wrapper, but it looks fairly straightforward: http://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/

Comment: GPG sounds pretty good, but for encrypting _and_ zipping, something like zip, 7zip, or equivalents which do both would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Use -P option on zip, or apply [gnupg](http://www.gnupg.org/) over tar/zip you create.

There are certainly many other possibilities.